# Tomcat how to connect base site url to my project in server xml

Tags: java, tomcat, webserver, tomcat7

My server xml file:

`<Host name="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>`

My project is in webapps folder (webapps/MyProject/). When i go to site URL, tomcat main page is coming not my main page of MyProject.

Thanks.

Comment: I know welcome file tag in web.xml but it is not the case. I want to locate MyProject in $TOMCAT_HOME/MyProject and I change appbase attribute in host tag ( appBase="MyProject") but it is not working. How I connect $TOMCAT_HOME/MyProject to myIP or domain name?

Answer (score 0):

By default the page it opens is of default tomcat page when you try accessing it with following URL,

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

You need to override that page. Inside $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml there is a section called < welcome-file-list> and it looks like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

The default servlet attempts to load the index.* files in the order listed. You may easily override the index.jsp file by creating an index.html file at $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ROOT. It's somewhat common for that file to contain a new static home page or a redirect to a servlet's main page. A redirect would look like:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://localhost:8080/some/path/to/servlet/homepage/">
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Ref: https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_override_the_default_home_page_loaded_by_Tomcat.3F